# Azure activity logs not displaying any write data

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I'm trying to set up logging for a storage resource (table specifically, though it seems like the activity log doesn't and just logs the entire Storage account).

The logging seems to log my ListKeys operations, occasional access from ApplicationInsights, but isn't logging any writes/reads I'm making to the tables themselves through either my app or the Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer. This table has been written to multiple times over the past few weeks, but yet none of that activity shows up.

Am I misinterpreting [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-overview-activity-logs) page, which states that this activity log should track posts/deletes?  Do I need any additional setup to track these operations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my understanding, you could leverage [Storage Analytics logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/using-storage-analytics) to log the operations on your storage. For the detailed operations that are logged for the corresponding storage service, you could refer to this official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/storage-analytics-logged-operations-and-status-messages).

According to your description, I have tested my operations against table storage by using REST API and Storage Explorer Tool. Here is my test result, you could refer to it.

**Table Storage Analytics logging**

[image]

**Table Storage Metrics**

[image]

As noted in this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/about-storage-analytics-logging):

> As requests are logged, Storage Analytics will upload intermediate results as blocks. **Periodically**, Storage Analytics will commit these blocks and make them available as a blob.

In summary, please follow this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/enabling-and-configuring-storage-analytics) to enable and configure Storage Analytics, then wait for some time and check your table storage logging.

Comment: Unfortunately neither of these logs have exactly what I need (I was looking for logging which user performed the action in those Table Storage Metrics, it looks like I need to do something myself for this).  But your answer does answer my question, which helped me clear up my misconceptions. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you are leveraging the Azure Activity log, remember that it is meant for control plane operations. So listkeys would show up there.

if you are looking for data plane operations (such as entity writes into a table), then make sure Diagnostics are turned on inside the Storage account that you are writing to.

Comment: I have those enabled as well, and they also only show QueryTable and QueryEntities operations, even though I'm doing writes.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Activity Log is only for management plane records through Azure Resource Manager (ARM), specifically PUT/DELETE/POST which includes ListKeys which is an HTTP POST.

For storage analytics logging, you can use [this article to see the types of data logged](https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/Storage-Analytics-Logged-Operations-and-Status-Messages).